# Sending / Forwarding variable arguments in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, variables, ios5, variable-assignment

I know this is possible in other programming languages. Suppose we have the following arrangement:

```
- (void) myMethod:(NSString*)variables, ... {
    // Handle business here.
}

- (void) anotherMethod:(NSString*)variables, ... {
    // We want to pass these variable arguments for handling
    [self myMethod:variables, ...]; // Do not pass GO
}

// Start the party:
[self anotherMethod:@"arg1", @"arg2", @"arg3", @"arg4", nil];
```

What's the trick to get this working in ObjC?

Comment: Have you [looked at this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible in objective-c . You can find good write up on that [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html).

Comment: but how does it help to forward variadic calls?

Comment: This link doesn't tell _anything_ that help achieve what OP wants, especially how to forward varargs.

Comment: Yes. It uses `va_list`,`va_args`, and typically doesn't solve [**this problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26102660/1594913).

Comment: @JBL, The problem you have mentioned has nothing to do with variable argument passing. It is a specific glitch in UIAlertView. The link does help the questioner thus the answer is accepted. I don't think the negative vote is justified.

Comment: @Vignesh There is indeed a glitch in the UIAlertView, but this could have actually been solved if there was a proper way to forward variadic arguments. (Oh and btw, I didn't vote at all on the question, because I wouldn't say that it is not useful, as shown by the fact it has been accepted)