# Forward variadic arguments for a UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, ios7, variadic-functions

I'm trying to set up a very simple `UIAlertView` with a text edit, an Ok and a cancel button, and I want to disable the Ok button based on the content of the text edit.

To be able to retain the delegate so that he doesn't go away before the alert view (and thus cause a crash as soon as the user does something with the alert view), I've subclassed it. Now, I want to be able to forward the `otherButtonTitles` argument from my init method to the `UIAlertView` init method, but for some reasons, simply doing that:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
            message:(NSString*)message
           delegate:(id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/)delegate
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... {

    if (self = [super initWithTitle:title 
                            message:message 
                           delegate:delegate 
                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle 
                  otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles, nil]) {
        //stuff
    }
```

*only adds the first element of the args to the alert view*. I've found that I can actually manually add the buttons to the alert view using this:

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, otherButtonTitles);
for (NSString *buttonTitle = otherButtonTitles; buttonTitle != nil; buttonTitle = va_arg(args, NSString*)) {
  [self addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
}
va_end(args);
```

but then, my `alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton` delegate method isn't called anymore, [**with the probable explanation in this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20501090/1594913).

Thus, how can I forward correctly my `otherButtonTitles` to the `UIAlertView` init method correctly?

Comment: I was always bothered by the fact, that in C you can collect varargs with va_list, but have no way to pass it further to another variadic function. We know both abi and bounds, but no sir.

Comment: Btw, if you are familiar with objc runtime (objc_msgSend), and sure that the number of other buttons never exceeds some fixed limit, you may use hack described here: http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html

Comment: @user3125367 Thanks for the link, but this is completely unfeasible here, as I am bound by the signature of the `UIAlertView` init method, which doesn't take a va_list but variadic arguments...

Comment: Not sure whether you missed VERY WRONG solution at bottom of the page. It addresses the issue in, well, very wrong way :) But it should work.

Comment: Yeah, no, I'd like to avoid such way of doing...

Comment: You should depend on the library to provide you with an equivalent API that either takes a `va_list` or lets you add it one by one (which this library does). If there is a bug with that alternative API, then that's the library's problem.

Comment: @newacct Yes but I don't want to find who's responsible, I want a solution :/

Comment: @JBL You are looking for non-hacky solution to hacky problem. Please report back if you find it.

Comment: @user3125367 I think you're right. I've got a solution to my specific problem, but that doesn't address the problem of this question (that is, forwarding variadic arguments)

Answer (score 0):

Let's reduce keystrokes then:

```
NSMutableArray *otherButtonTitles = [NSMutableArray array];
// .. collect varargs into ^^^

#define T(n) ([otherButtonTitles objectAtIndex:n])
#define CASE(n, ...) case n: self = [super initWithTitle:title \
                                                 message:message \ 
                                                delegate:delegate \
                                       cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle \
                                       otherButtonTitles:__VA_ARGS__, nil]; \
                             break

switch ([otherButtonTitles count]) {
    CASE(0, nil);
    CASE(1, T(0));
    CASE(2, T(0), T(1));
    CASE(3, T(0), T(1), T(2));
    // ... repeat until bored ...
    default: @throw @"too many buttons"; // or return nil
}
```